# Accessing div element inside another element within same parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I'm working on a small angular app. Below is my html snippet. I want the div ( *id = metaoptions* ) to toggle between show/hide when I click on img ( *id = myImg*) and it is not working

```
<div>
    <div #metaoptions id="metaoptions" class="meta-options" [hidden]="true" *ngFor="let option of metaOptions">
        <span>{{option.label}}</span>
    </div>
    <img id="myImg" (click)="metaoptions.hidden = (!metaoptions.hidden)"  src="blabla.jpeg">
</div>
```

Same approach worked at different place in my code. I toggled image for *mouseover* and *mouseout* events

```
<tr class="abc" (mouseover)="helpImg.hidden = false" (mouseout)="helpImg.hidden = true">
    <td class="xyz">
        {{setting.label}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="zxc" >
         <mat-checkbox>
         </mat-checkbox>
        <img #helpImg [hidden]="true" class="help-img" src="/assets/icons/dark/help_img.svg" (click)="showHelp(setting.name)"/>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You're using a bizarre approach to Angular. I strongly suggest using *ngIf and not writing TS code in the template (use methods instead). This is a fairly simple task using normal Angular code.

Comment: @WillAlexander I couldn't do that as there are multiple copies of parent div as it is in another *ngFor. If you think there is some way, please feel free to answer the post.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML:

```html
<div id="metaoptions" *ngIf="metaOptionsVisible"></div>
<img id="myImg" (click)="onClickImg()">
```

In your TS:

```js
onClickImg() {
  this.metaOptionsVisible = !this.metaOptionsVisible;
}
```